# Using SVCUTIL.EXE to generate DataContracts for NOAA Forcast

Tags: c#, xsd, datacontract, datacontractserializer, svcutil.exe

I'm writing an API for NOAA forecast data, and I'm trying to get the information from a XML document like [this](http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=40.78158&lon=-73.96648&FcstType=dwml) into a de-serialized object.  I Downloaded the [schema](http://graphical.weather.gov/xml/DWMLgen/schema/DWML.xsd) and it's two dependacies ([meta_data.xsd](http://graphical.weather.gov/xml/DWMLgen/schema/meta_data.xsd) & [ndfd_data.xsd](http://graphical.weather.gov/xml/DWMLgen/schema/ndfd_data.xsd) ) and tried running this command

```
svcutil C:\DWML.xsd /dconly
```

But it returns with

```
Error: Cannot read D:\DWML.xsd.
Cannot load file D:\DWML.xsd as an Assembly. Check the FusionLogs for more information.
```

Can someone please walk me through the steps to create data contract for this xml document?

If there is an easier way to get this information into a easily querable form that doesn't require Data Contracts I'm willing to change my approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to supply all the xsd files to SvcUtil like so

```
svcutil *.xsd /dconly
```

However trying this with NOAA schema gives bunch of errors and it suggested to use `/importXmlTypes`. But the following did not work for me either:

```
svcutil *.xsd /dconly /ser:XmlSerializer /importXmlTypes
```

Finally, used [Xsd2Code](http://xsd2code.codeplex.com/releases/view/22222)

```
xsd2Code.exe DWML.xsd
```

and it worked like a charm.

Comment: can you post the generated code? I still can seem to get it to work

Comment: It is over 5000 lines.  What was the error with `xsd2Code.exe DWML.xsd`?

Comment: nvm sorry i tried the second line of code before reading :0.  I installed xsd2code but I cant find the .exe

Comment: It created a bunch of errors like this: private List<System.Nullable<>> valueField; and idea how to resolve these